# How to Force Visitor to Login after 3 Consecutive Download

Tags: 7, users, files

My site serves downloadable files.

How can I force them to login/register after downloading 3 consecutive files?

Is there any available modules for this? If not, is there a sample script to start playing with?

I'm using drupal 7.

Comment: are the file downloads recorded in any way?is it just file links?consecutive? maybe you need to add Commerce like functionality and make downloads as a product in order to control and record the downloads and then easily trigger the login sequence..

Also Rules module could help you

Comment: A file. A zip file that is located on my server. I don't know what you mean by file links. You mean a link from an external site? If yes, then no. The file is located on my server. What you mean by commerce like functionality? I will create it my own or does it exist already?

Comment: You need to use private filesystem and save all accesses in your database. Would require pretty neat module. Something like [commerce file](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_file), I guess.

Comment: @Mołot I don't need commerce module. All I want is force the visitors to register or login to the site after download 3 files (zip file). All my files are free source code bundled in zip file.

Comment: @jaypabs I didn't say you need this module. All I meant to say you need to control access in a way similar to the way this one does.

Comment: @Mołot ah okay...no problem...