# Download file after login

Tags: 7, ajax, users, files

I'm looking for direction with regards to how to get a file to download only after you are logged in, and to be prompted to login if you try to download it and then upon a correct submission, have that file automatically download.  The login form is to be presented in a modal dialog upon clicking the file when logged out.

Right now I have the modal form displaying when clicking the file download link, but I essentially need to reconstruct the login mechanism to work via AJAX I believe.  This includes validations and establishing the user's logged in session.  I'm not sure how to go about it... thoughts from the Drupal Answers community?

Comment: check this module https://drupal.org/project/file_access

Comment: have a look in to this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80284/how-to-force-visitor-to-login-after-3-consecutive-download

Answer (score 1):

[Private files download permission](https://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission)

> Version 1.x provided "two useful features which Drupal itself is
>   missing: a simple permission to allow downloading of private files by
>   role, plus the ability to combine both public and private downloads".
>
> Version 2.x removes the "global" permission and implements a
>   per-directory by-user and by-role filter instead, to let the
>   administrator better tweak the whole website and increment the overall
>   security.

with this module you can achieve your requirement by following this tutorial [source](http://getlevelten.com/blog/randall-knutson/requiring-registration-download-files-drupal)

Hope it helps you!